# Is this deadlock about httpclient?

Tags: java, multithreading, request, httpclient

Recently my program got dead while postting a http request,here is the thread dump

```
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:136)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:152)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:270)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:140)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:260)
    at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:161)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:153)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:271)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:123)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:254)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:195)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:86)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:72)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:214)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:160)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:136)
    at com.peony.crawler.core.LoginController.testLogin(LoginController.java:109)
    at com.peony.crawler.core.LoginController.getLogin(LoginController.java:69)
    - locked <0x00000000f0938a08> (a com.peony.crawler.core.LoginController)
    at com.peony.crawler.core.CrawlerTaskService.getLogin(CrawlerTaskService.java:76)
    at com.peony.crawler.core.CrawlerTask.getLogin(CrawlerTask.java:162)
    at com.peony.crawler.core.CrawlerTask.craw(CrawlerTask.java:77)
    at com.peony.crawler.core.CrawlerTask.run(CrawlerTask.java:70)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Is there anybody who have ever met the same question with me? 
And who can help me find out why this happened?
The version of httpclient i use is 4.3.5
The version of my jvm is Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.60-b09, mixed mode)
The version of my os is CentOS release 6.5 (Final)
Thank you very much!

Comment: Request probably timed out, your thread is runnable.

Comment: But how can it explain that it's blocked here for more than three hours and there is no sign to indicate it will return.Mean while I have set both the connection timeout and the socket timeout to 30 seconds.

Comment: It could be caused by a condition you're waiting on. I've recently had a similar problem and it was fixed when I removed all of the code that "blocked".

Comment: Finally I find out the cause of this problem. There is no default connection timeout and socket timeout for httpclient. When I set a suitable timeout for them, the problem is resolved!

Comment: There is a [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36791569/why-thread-of-sslsocketimpl-performinitialhandshake-is-always-runnable).
I found it in [apache JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-1589).